# how to create a fully close window for Exam web app

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am creating a exam portal and I want to create a window which is full screen so that the chances of malpractices can be reduced. I don't know how to do it

Comment: See this : [Fullscreen API Guide on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API/Guide)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot force full screen permanently on a browser, for somewhat obvious reasons (imagine a spam website abusing it). However, what you can do, is detect a blur event on the window and open another window alerting the user to return to the test.

Just add this javascript:

```
var myWindow
window.addEventListener("blur", function(){
refocusWindow()
})
window.addEventListener("focus", function(){
myWindow.removeEventListener("blur", refocus)
myWindow.close()
})

function refocusWindow(){
myWindow=window.open("", "myWindow")
myWindow.addEventListener("blur", refocus)
}

function refocus(){
myWindow.close()
setTimeout(function(){
if (document.visibilityState!="visible"){
refocusWindow()
}
},1)
}
```

Note that the page opened will be blank - you can change it by writing in HTML using `myWindow.document.write("HTML code in string format")`